openJDK 22 install Rasppbery PI 3b+
I am trying to install through the SDKMAN openjdk java version 22, but no success. I am getting this error, what is the solution?
**root@psd:~ $ sdk install java 22-amzn**

Downloading: java 22-amzn

In progress...

######################################################################### 100.0%

Repackaging Java 22-amzn...

Done repackaging...

Installing: java 22-amzn
mv: target '/home/ias/.sdkman/candidates/java/22-amzn': No such file or directory
Done installing!


Setting java 22-amzn as default.

**root@psd:~ $ sdk current java**
Not using any version of java

I am trying to install through the SDKMAN openjdk java version 22, but no success
